# Merge two strings in kotlin

Tags: string, arraylist, kotlin

I have two strings

```
val a = "abc"
val b = "xyz"
```

I want to merge it and need output like below

> **axbycz**

I added both strings to arraylist and then flatmap it

```
val c = listOf(a, b)

val d = c.flatMap {
    it.toList()
}
```

but not getting the desired result

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `zip` function. It creates a list of pairs with "adjacent" letters. You can then use `joinToString` with a transformer to create your final result.

```
a.zip(b) // Returns the list [(a, x), (b, y), (c, z)]
 .joinToString("") { (a, b) -> "$a$b" } // Joins the list back to a string with no separator
```

Comment: Nice one. I didn't know `zip` acts directly over the string as an `Iterable<Char>`, like in many FP languages. I had a similar solution but I was doing `a.toList()` and `b.toList()`.

Comment: @m0skit0 exactly my thought, really nice :)

Comment: @m0skit0 Kotlin provides [overloads for `CharSequence`s](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/zip.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can always use a simple loop, assuming both strings have the same size. That way You only allocate a `StringBuilder` and counter variable, without any `lists`, `arrays` or `pairs`:

```
val a = "abc"
val b = "xyz"
val sb = StringBuilder()
for(i in 0 until a.length){
    sb.append(a[i]).append(b[i])
}
val d = sb.toString()
```

Comment: Works but not idiomatic. This is Java written in Kotlin.

Comment: @m0skit0 it is more efficient, but for small data set it's probably irrelevant. I ran this and accepted answer in JVM 10 million times - loop averaged 340ms, zip 840ms. With 184 char input string loop was 9.5sec, zip 31sec.

Comment: @Pawel I had performance in mind too. Take a look at my answer

Comment: Readability is generally more important than premature optimizations. I can immediately understand marstran's answer. For yours I need to 1) read more lines of code, and 2) figure out what you are doing on your for loop.

Comment: @WilliMentzel I looped that too but it seems to have same overhead as zip, averaging 850ms in 10 million loop as well.

Comment: @Pawel i didn't check it, but that would be sad :(

Comment: @Pawel could you publish a playground with your benchmark? https://play.kotlinlang.org

Comment: @WilliMentzel I used to do it locally but if You want to see for yourself: [playground](https://pl.kotl.in/HJJSOFvE4).

Comment: @Pawel I learned two things: mine is the slowest (i deleted my answer xD) and yours is the fastest, definitely so much faster that I would sacrifice readability for it (even though I think it's readability is good) :) thx for the benchmark +1

Answer (score 0):

marstran's answer is really concise and Pawels answer is really fast. Using [`buildString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/build-string.html) you can have to best of both worlds:

```
buildString {
    a.zip(b).forEach { (a, b) ->
        append(a).append(b)
    }
}
```

`buildString` creates a `StringBuilder` and offers it as receiver in the lambda. It returns the built string.

<sub>Try it out here: [Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/B1zftOdEV). Thanks to Pawel for creating the original benchmark.</sub>